# Canvas: trying to draw too large(144609280bytes) bitmap, at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw

Tags: android, android-layout, picasso, android-glide

I get image from a web service, i do following to display it in imageView.

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageURL).fit().centerCrop().into(ivNews);
```

2 days ago a `2048X1600` resolution images was uploaded on server, and all of sudden app start crashing with this exception `Canvas: trying to draw too large(144609280bytes) bitmap`

There is a possibility that the image uploaded on server was higher than the mentioned resolution, and server can upload more high resolution images in future as well.

I read [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) article, Its mentioned that `glide` is faster and better than picasso in terms of performance,

It also mentioned that if you use, `.fit().centerCrop()` then the performance is better, but i was already using these, and got these error message

I want to solve this by using picasso

Comment: Will it work `Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.chat_image_placeholder).resize(1024, 800).onlyScaleDown().fit().centerCrop().into(thumbnailView)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use `scaleDown()` to scale the image if it is of bigger size. You could use it like below.

```
Picasso  
.with(context)
.load(<image_url>)
.resize(2048, 1600)
.onlyScaleDown() // the image will only be resized if it's bigger than 2048x 1600 pixels.
.into(<image_view>);
```

Comment: Thanks, so using a bigger value on resize will be better for performance? but this will compromise on image quality. right?

Comment: You could choose a threshold limit of certain resolution. say for example (1080x720), anything above it will be scaled down. Yes, scaling down might distort your image.

Comment: Your answer sounds perfectly reasonable while the actual behaviour on 2.5.2 `java.lang.IllegalStateException: onlyScaleDown can not be applied without resize` is not. What a shame for Picasso :(

Comment: When to use `fit()` and when to use `resize()`? Can you please clear to me?