# Load Image through Glide in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-glide

This Code is not showing any image in imageview. I am getting an Exception that a file size is too large. Help me. Can anyone Please Explain what I am doing wrong?

```
  Bundle arguments = getArguments();
  if (arguments != null) {
      String name = arguments.get("FoodName").toString();
      String image = arguments.get("FoodImage").toString();

      txtfoodname.setText(name);
      Glide.with(this).load(image).into(imgfood);
  }
```

Comment: what is the stack trace? (If the file size is too large try a smaller image file.)

Comment: i am getting this image from my recycler view than why this image is showing in recycler view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canvas: trying to draw too large(144609280bytes) bitmap, at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863447/canvas-trying-to-draw-too-large144609280bytes-bitmap-at-android-view-display)